# Extending functions to homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Is there a homeomorphism $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ (co)restricts to a homeomorphism $f:(0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$?

I am a bit rusty in general topology, but I think that $\mathbb{Q} \cong (0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $ \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q} \cong (0,1) - \mathbb{Q}$. So there wouldn't be any easy contradiction. So is there another strategy or a counterexample to (dis)prove the statement?

More generally, given a space $X$ and $Y,Z\subset X$ such that $|X|=|Z|$, is there a homeo sending $Y$ to $Z$? Of course it is false in general (e.g $Y$ has some topological property that $Z$ hasn't). But is there some conditions on $Y$ and $Z$ (and $X$?) such that there is such homeomorphisms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Take any order-isomorphism $f_0:(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$; then taking Dedekind completions of both sides, $f_0$ extends uniquely to an order-isomorphism $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ which is then such a homeomorphism.  More explicitly, any piecewise-linear homeomorphism $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that the endpoints of the linear pieces in both the domain and codomain are all rational will map $(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.

As for your general question, as you observe, there are easy counterexamples, and I doubt there is anything you can say with much generality.  Really, the case where there *does* exist a homeomorphism of $X$ sending $Y$ to $Z$ is the exception, not the rule.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure, by Dedekind completions, you mean sending the equivalence class of a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ to the equivalence class of $(f(x_n))$ ? And yes, for the general case, I agree that it seems too vague to have an explicit answer.

Comment: Not Cauchy sequences, but Dedekind cuts.  Cauchy sequences don't quite work (without saying something more complicated) because $(0,1)$ is not complete (you can have Cauchy sequences that approach $0$ or $1$).  Dedekind cuts are defined using only the ordering, so they are preserved by any order-isomorphism.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks again !

Comment: In respect of the question's last paragraph, is the correct answer perhaps that it is generally the case that when $X$ is the completion of $Z$ and $f_0$ is a homeomorphism then the completion of $f_0$ will the the homeomorphism sought?

Answer (score 2):

For a constructive example, first here's a homeomorphism $g:(0, 1)\to \mathbb{R}_{+}$ whose restriction is a homeomorphism $(0, 1)\cap \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}_{+}$:
$$\begin{align}
g(x) &= \frac {x} {1-x} \\
&= \frac {1} {{\frac {1} {x}} - 1} \\
\end{align}
$$

This $g$ easily extends to a homeomorphism $h:(-1, 1)\to \mathbb{R}$ which maps rationals to rationals: $h(x) = -g(-x)$ for $x < 0$, and $g(0) = 0$. Composing h with $x \mapsto 2x - 1: (0, 1) \to (-1, 1)$ gives a homeomorphism $f$ as desired.

As for your more general inquiry about homeomorphisms that in some sense preserve subspaces, perhaps there are results that generalize this case,  but that's a question for serious topologists. The [Tietze Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) comes to mind, but it's only a vague similarity; it wouldn't help here, for example.